# First attempt at a circuit design for Raspberry Pi

Tags: circuit-design, raspberry-pi, gpio, servo, fan

The last time I did any electronic design myself was about 12 years ago, I'm hoping to turn this schematic into a PCB and solder it all up eventually but I am so out of my depth trying to relearn this stuff!

My requirement is a circuit that can do 4 things:

1. Control 2 PWM 12V Fans (These will always be in sync so one PWM signal would work)
2. Control 2 Servos (These will always be in sync too)
3. Operate a standard RGB LED Strip (Not addressable)
4. Measure humidity and temperature

I'm adding a display too but Ill drive this off the HDMI using a mini screen. (Unless it would be easy to add an Liquid Crystal to this? Might be over complex)

So far I've done a bit of reading around and come up with this monster of a diagram, please forgive the layout last time I did this it was by hand and finding decent software and learning it is proving challenging!

[image]

My questions are:

1. Does this seem I'm going in the completely wrong direction?
2. If not, then can any improvements be suggested? I'm happy to learn and attempt to make them myself but any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: One tip for the layout: use ground and power labels / symbols next to each IC instead of drawing long spaghetti wires.

Comment: Which FET type for RGB? Also why would the fan PWM specifically need a level shifter if that is a common computer fan? Do you have the specs for fan PWM input?

Comment: What is powering the 3V3 and 5V rails?

Comment: The PWM pins from the Fans are normally outputs. You seem to be trying to use them as a control input?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @DamienD

Comment: @Justme not sure what FET is? But something cheap and cheerful like this: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32813086269.html

These are the fans: https://arctic.de/en/F8-PWM-PST/ACFAN00204A

Comment: @Mat The power would come from the Raspberry pi, its a 2.5A 5.1V supply to the Pi itself which it shares with the GPIO pins.

Comment: @PMF The diagram was shameless stolen from this question... https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118486/control-a-12v-dc-fan-via-pwm-and-a-level-shifter

Comment: The 3.3V GPIO outputs are unlikely to drive the nfets to saturation which will cause heat issues and possibly not turn the LEDs fully on.   Also, the fan PWM inputs may need to be 5V signals, you'll need to check the fan datasheets.

Comment: @DeanFranks Planning to use these MOSFETS which have a low threshold voltage so should be ok I think? https://thepihut.com/products/n-channel-power-mosfet

Comment: @PMF Fans have PWM input to control speed.

Comment: There is a nice CAD program that will take you from schematic capture to Gerber files that is free but they do ask for a donation.  It works very well. I am using Version 5.19. I have read that there may some bad copies out there at version 6. It has no limits on layers or size. There are others as well.

Comment: Classic newbie mistake using threshold voltage to source your MOSFET.  Look at the on-resistance vs. gate to source voltage (figure 12) on the datasheet.

Comment: Take a look at the datasheet figure 12 as recommended by @evildemonic.  Vthresh is when the MOSFET starts turning on, not when it is saturated.  Using that mosfet will definitely not work being directly driven by the RPI GPIO.  Also, remember that the mosfet gate load is capacitive, when switched, the current draw on the GPIO pin will dramatically exceed the max rated current and could cause permanent damage to the RPI processor.  Gate drivers can deliver a couple of amps for a reason.  All of this is made worse if you are driving with a PWM signal.